# How to update table row with jQuery-Tabledit and Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, tabledit

In Laravel I need to specify the row ID as part of the request URL in order to update it, for example: http://localhost/contacts/16

The problem is when using jQuery-Tabledit, as it requires an URL while initializing (on page load).

So the question is, how to set the current row ID as URL in jQuery-Tabledit?

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="contactsTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th class="tabledit-toolbar-column"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if($contacts)
        @foreach ($contacts as $contact)
            <tr id="{{$contact->id}}">
                <td><span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">{{$contact->id}}</span><input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$contact->id}}" disabled=""></td>
                <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">{{$contact->first_name}}</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="first_name" value="{{$contact->first_name}}" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
                <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">{{$contact->last_name}}</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="last_name" value="{{$contact->last_name}}" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
           </tr>
       @endforeach
   @endif
</tbody>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#contactsTable').Tabledit({
        url: 'http://localhost/contacts/22',
        saveButton: false,
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'id'],
            editable: [[1, 'first_name'], [2, 'last_name']]
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, url: 'http://localhost/contacts/22' is the problem. The code above works as expected, but updates only row 22 as jQuery-Tabledit URL is fix-coded to row 22.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your jquery its located within the current blade. Therfore these bracket: `{{ }}, {!! !!}` only will be considered as templating when you use the extension `.blade.php.`

So what you could do its simply use blade to echo the `contact id` using the brackets.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#contactsTable').Tabledit({
        url: 'http://localhost/contacts/'+{!! $contact->id !!},
        saveButton: false,
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'id'],
            editable: [[1, 'first_name'], [2, 'last_name']]
        }
    });
});
```

or just serialize the contact collection to json:

```
$('#contactsTable').on('click', function(){
   let contacts = {!! $contacts->toJson() !!};

   // now you can access all attributes that are defined in Contacts model 
   // example contact id 

   let contact_id = contacts.id; 


}
```

Comment: I can't just add the contact ID while Tabledit is initializing (when document ready), as we don't know what row the user is going to edit. Similar answer for the second approach, even when I catch the 'click' event, I would need to re-initialize the whole table $('#contactsTable').Tabledit() which is a no-go.

Comment: fair enough, but still no matter which row user its updating! You simply get the current contact id so then when u recieve the post data in backend you can validate and check what user has updated and what not! In your jquery that you have posted obviously a post request ain't going to work since first of you do not have the csrf! And I do not see how u are getting that 'id' to the controller !

Comment: I simplified the code above in order to emphasize the actual problem. The original code do have a csrf token and a hidden input field "_method=PUT" in order to trick Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it on the server side, created a separate Route just for updating the data via Tabledit which does not require the row ID as part of the URL (I included it in the POST request):

```
Route::post('/contacts/updatetable','ContactsController@updateTable');
```

Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function updateTable(Request $request)
    {
        // Save the data.
        $contact = Contact::find($request->input('id'));
    }

    ...
}
```

But still would be nice to know if there is any way on client-side (jQuery-Tabledit).